# ajax+form.submit doesnt work while ajax alone works

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, submit

I have a problem using jquery ajax+form.submit() method. As I submit the form it always triggers the error section in Ajax request. The request status is always 200 OK but the Response in Firebug just shows the whole html document.

This is my form

```
<form method="GET" id="login_form">
    <input class="text_field" type="text" placeholder="El. paÅ¡tas" name="email_inp"/>
    <input class="text_field" type="password" placeholder="******" name="pass_inp"/>
    <button id="sign_in">OK</button>
</form>
```

And this is my jQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login_form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'index.php/notes',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ZWdpczoxMjM0NTY=');    
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('status: '+ textStatus);
                alert('error: '+ errorThrown);
            },
            success:function(json) {
                alert("works");
                $('#msg').html(json[0].text);
                $('#msg').html(JSON.stringify(json));
            }
        });
});
});
```

If I delete this:

```
$("#login_form").submit(function() {
});
```

It works and gives the data properly in Firebugs http response and div I have marked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u came across this problem because u didn't stop the default event , for the form , the defaut event is submit , u chose ajax to submit the form so u should stop the default submit event ,

```
$("#login_form").submit(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({....});
});
```

here is the solution . good luck ! :D